# how to change file encoding correctly

Tags: android

I just opened my Android Studio, but one file Looks like this: 
[image]

But yesterday everythings works great and I haven't Change the file Encoding. I tried to convert the file to other encodings. But nothing changes. 
These are my Settings:
[image]

Here is the link to the file: [file](https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=DB700463EBEC6BC9&resid=DB700463EBEC6BC9%2123786&authkey=AIXqcgBZJ5jyGns)

How to fix it?

Thanks for helping

Comment: I used UTF-8 for all three and also check box selected

Comment: Thanks. I changed all to UTF-8, cleaned and rebuild the Project. But still the same =(

Answer (score 0):

Filename looks german. Try change encoding to iso-8859-1. It would be easier to help you if you upload this file.

Comment: yes it's German. I tried to Change to iso-8859-1. But no change

Comment: Can you upload this file? I want to try opening it myself.

Comment: I am afraid you are right. Have you tried using "local history" on this file?